# Communication between two ARM chips over PCI-e

Tags: microprocessor, pcie, soc

I have a LX2162A CPU from NXP (datasheet is [here](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/302/LX2162AFS-2089757.pdf)), and 2 I.MX8.Quad, also from NXP (Datasheet is [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/IMX8MDQLQCEC.pdf))

**My goal**

My goal is to design a NUMA enabled system. A single instance of a mainline linux will run on one of the 2 MX8.Quad s. The other MX.8 should be connected to the previous MX8 via PCI-express (it has 2 PCI-e lanes).

The OS should see the cores of the second MX.8 and memory connected to it as a single system. It should see 8 cores, and 16 GB memory.

The LX2162A should be then connected to the second MX.8 . The OS should be able to see this as an optional extension.

**My question**

1. Are there some reference designs of connecting ARM processors via PCI-e such that a single instance of an OS running on one sees the other as a seamless extension? Any publication would be nice.
2. Intel uses QPI to do this between their XEON cpus. What is the equivalent for ARMs?

**My attempt to solution**

It appears that some server systems attempted to do all that. Here is defunct [Calxeda](https://www.datacenterdynamics.com/en/news/open-source-community-deploys-arm-microserver-cluster/), that tried to place multiple ARM processors on the same board, where the instance of the OS will see all of them as the same server, and will be able to seamlessly communicate with them, increasing the available core count.

At least that is what I read, correct me if I am wrong.

But I find no documentation on how that is done.

Here is [Dell](https://bit-tech.net/news/tech/cpus/dell-arm-servers/1/) playing with the same idea. 4 Armada SoC on the same board.

It seems, there are some work done on connecting multiple SoC over [PCI-E switch](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7831394)

However, in my case, I just want MX8.Quad <----> MX8.Quad <----> LS2162A. Thus I dont really need a switch (the MX.8 does not have one either).

I do not see anything in the last paper that indicates that the OS running in the DRAM of one SoC can seamlessly launch threads in another one.

Thus I need some idea on how to implement a solution that would enable the OS launched in the DRAM of one SoC can see the other SoC (may be over PIC-e), access the cores and RAM of the second one, and seamlessly launch threads of any program started in the first SoC on the second SoC.

A reference design, and open source document will be magnificent.

Of course the PCI-e data transfer will introduce a overhead, but I am willing to deal with it.

My hope is to improve the [Olimex Tukhla](https://olimex.wordpress.com/2021/04/06/our-most-complex-open-source-hardware-board-made-with-kicad-the-octa-core-imx8-quad-max-tukhla-is-completely-routed-and-now-on-prototype-production/) board with multiple SoC-s on the same board.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. it's a bit outside electronics' scope. You can connect devices through PCIe but there can be only one master on the bus. What you want to do is mostly low level driver development rather than electronics. For Q2, there is not "equivalent" for ARM. NUMA hardware is specific to a platform, AMD and Intel solution are different, but then it's mostly driver development (again). ARM mostly provide core IP, things like QPI would be specific to a SoC developer (NXP, Rockchip, Broadcom, etc.). If it hasn't been proposed by ARM that means nobody need it for ARM chips.

Comment: 2. I'm not sure you really know what you're starting when asking these kind of questions. HW development with 3 SoC of 2 types on a board, it's not that easy and you'll need some experience, so asking about PCIe is kind of freaky. Then you'll need low level software skill, I'm not sure that Linux will support NUMA over PCIe in few seconds on a custom board. So to get answers, get more precise questions rather than a vague question.